# in need for good tutorial on deploying ad-hoc

Tags: xcode4.5, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm writing an iphone application that sends email, sms and make phone calls.
since I can't test from the simulator that any of the code I wrote actually work, I'd like to deploy the application on my iphone without a developer license.

After searching the web and similar questions here I'm still looking for dummies tutorial (step 1...step 2...), can anyone refer me to one

thanks

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight provides an easy ad-hoc distribution system for testing apps. It's easy to add devices and their documentation is very helpful. Their website is https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/. And here is a great step-by-step tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/testing-with-testflight/.